# How do I redirect a user if they enter an invalid email using Passport OAuth2 (Swoop) and Node/Express?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am implementing Swoop (https://swoopnow.com/) authentication in my project and checking the type of emails entered by the user.

Let's say for example, I only want a user to enter a gmail account and nothing else.

When a user enters the permitted email type (gmail), I successfully authenticate them and return `user` in Passport's `done` function.

But, when a user enters a forbidden email type (yahoo, outlook, etc.), I return `false` in Passport's `done` function, which works fine, however I would like to redirect the user to an error page and let them know that their email is forbidden.

In Swoop, only an `unauthorized` message is displayed on the screen.

UPDATE: Here is my working code (thank you Aviv Lo!)

```
passport.use('swoop', new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://auth.swoop.email/oauth2/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://auth.swoop.email/oauth2/token',
    clientID: /* 'CLIENT_ID', */ 'swoop_fc8iff4kfmwffaz',
    clientSecret: /* 'CLIENT_SECRET', */ 'c2092c662280555d00ef4ca70e009bf88d8c3dcc86b70ca9bb17d6e9fc646dc9',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/swoop/callback'
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
    let user = jwtDecode(params.id_token);

    let allowedEmailDomain = 'gmail.com';
    let userEmailDomain = user.email.split('@');

    if (userEmailDomain[1] === allowedEmailDomain) {
        done(null, user);
    } else {
        done(null, false);
    }
  }));

/*****************
* Auth Routes
*****************/
// Swoop Login Route
app.get('/auth/swoop', passport.authenticate('swoop', { scope: ['email'] }));

// Callback function after authentication occurs
app.get('/auth/swoop/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('swoop', { session: true }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.redirect('/error')
    }

    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/bad'); }

    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/error')
        }

        return res.redirect('/good');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

/*****************
* Routes
*****************/
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Swoop! \
  <div><a href="/auth/swoop">Login</a></div> \
  <div><a href="/logout">Logout</a></div>');
});

app.get('/good', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.user) {
    res.send('This contains a secret. Welcome ' + req.user.email);
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});

app.get('/bad', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Email Forbidden.');
});

app.get('/error', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Error.');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Swoop Demo listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be considering changing your code a little bit.

```js
app.get('/auth/swoop',(req,res,next)=>{

  //Using passport-local
    passport.authenticate('swoop', {scope: ['email']},(err, user) => {

        // If errors
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/bad')
        }

        //If user object does not exist => login failed
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/bad'); }
        
        console.log((user));


        //If all good, log the dude in
        req.logIn(user, (err) => {
            
            // If errors
            if (err) {
                return res.redirect('/bad')
            }

            //Redirect the user to the correct page
            return res.redirect('/good')

        });

     

    })(req, res, next);


  

});
```

```
  passport.authenticate('swoop',(err, user) => {
     
    // Do some logic here to see if the user is logged in
    // otherwise just res.redirect the user here to somewhere you want
    // You will have access to res here because you wrap it in the route
    })(req, res, next)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion, I would do this if I was using local strategy, however I'm using oauth2 strategy

Comment: But it also works with Oauth. The concept of redirecting the user is the same. `passport.autheticate` gives you access to the user info (or token )while the route itself gives you the ability to redirect the users.

Comment: I tried implementing it, but the server keeps loading and doesn't take me to the Swoop page for entering my email. I noticed this is the case when removing `{scope: ['email']}` or adding it with your suggestion

Comment: So it just hanged there both with and without the scope?

Comment: Yeah it hangs in both cases

Comment: Ah. I might know where the problem is. I have updated my answer. Because you need  to add `(req, res, next)` at the end.

Comment: Nice that fixed the loading issue, but it should be after the end bracket for `passport.authenticate`. Now the loading is gone, but I receive a message that says "AuthorizationError: The request is missing a required parameter:scope". I put scope to fix the issue, but now any logic inside the `passport.authenticate` doesn't work

Comment: What's your logic inside `passport.autheticate`?

Comment: I just check my code, it should be `passport.authenticate(......)(req,res,next)` instead of `app.get(...)(req,res,next)`

Comment: `app.get('/auth/swoop', (req, res, next) => {passport.authenticate('swoop, {scope: ['email']}, (error, user) => {if (user) res.redirect('/success') } else {res.redirect('/error')}})(req, res, next)})`

Comment: So the logic doesnt work even after you change the location of the req,res,next

Comment: I change my answer again and maybe this will work. If it doesnt, check what's the output of `console.log(user)` above/

Comment: Ok so I tried your suggestion, when I enter the correct email it says the site can't be reached, and when I enter an incorrect email, it doesn't do any redirects. The console doesn't print anything in both scenarios

Comment: The site cant be reached? Maybe update your answer with your current code. So other people can also see it

Comment: Ok I just had to restart the server to fix the 'site not found', but it still does not do any redirects

Comment: No it still does not redirect to other pages if the user is authenticated or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222208/discussion-between-aviv-lo-and-husseinfawazbc).